# MATLAB's 'meshgrid' in C

Tags: c, matlab

i like to use a library or function in C which could perform the same function as performed by **meshgrid** in MATLAB.

looking for support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you need a function or library for this.

[This](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) says "[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y) transforms the domain specified by vectors x and y into arrays X and Y, which can be used to evaluate functions of two variables"

If the vector is something like "a:b" then you can use a `for` statement to create the appropriate matrix.

If you post more details then maybe we can help you more!